# How to solve error Cannot read property '1' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, redux, preloader

So guys, I'm making preloader for my React App but I have an error.

---

I'm using **thunk** to change status of preloader (true/false) and in component it looks like:

```
{isLoading === true ? <Preloader />  :
                <div className="daily-weather-container">
                    <div className="daily-title">Daily Weather</div>
                    <div className="row scrolling-wrapper ">
                        <div className="col-lg-2 box-daily-weather">
                            {getWeatherStatistic(1)}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
const getWeatherStatistic = (value) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="date-box">5 June, Friday</div>
                <div className="temp-day">{Math.ceil(dailyData.daily[value].temp.day)}°C</div>
                <div className="feels-like">Feels like: {Math.ceil(dailyData.daily[value].feels_like.day)}°C</div>
                <div className="daily-weather-condition">Conditions: {dailyData.daily[value].weather.map(e => e.main)}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

And It works, but the problem is here `{getWeatherStatistic(1)}`. `1` - object index which I get from ajax request. So this error happened because, when the user open my App the state is empty, so it can't gets index object (obviously it not exists before making request).

---

So how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is `getWeatherStatistic` a *function* or an *object*?

Comment: @Gh05d Added code, sorry, just forgot..

Comment: What value has `dailyData` when it is called? Can you log it? If it has no value, then either your `isLoading` is wrong or your error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assure yourself dailyData.daily is a proper array and it won't crash

```
const getWeatherStatistic = (value) => {
    if(dailyData && Array.isArray(dailyData.daily){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="date-box">5 June, Friday</div>
                <div className="temp-day">{Math.ceil(dailyData.daily[value].temp.day)}°C</div>
                <div className="feels-like">Feels like: {Math.ceil(dailyData.daily[value].feels_like.day)}°C</div>
                <div className="daily-weather-condition">Conditions: {dailyData.daily[value].weather.map(e => e.main)}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else{
        return (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to get `daily[1]` but daily is `undefined`. An easy solution could be:

```
const getWeatherStatistic = (value) => {
  const { daily = [] } = dailyData || {}
  const {
    temp = {},
    feels_like = {},
    weather = []
    } = daily[value] || {}
  return (
      <div>
          <div className="date-box">5 June, Friday</div>
          <div className="temp-day">{temp.day ? Math.ceil(temp.day) : ''}°C</div>
          <div className="feels-like">Feels like: {feels_like.day ? Math.ceil(feels_like.day) : ''}°C</div>
          <div className="daily-weather-condition">Conditions: {weather.map(e => e.main)}</div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

So you make sure anything breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this happened because variable `isLoading` is `true` by default (in the component or in the store). It would be great if you can post your store, reducer, and component.